# Connection is in established state even after connection.close() call

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, impala

I am writing code to access impala using JDBC driver provided by the cloudera . And it works perfectly .

But , I am facing a small problem,..

After closing a connection , when i am checking the connections using netstat -an | grep -i 21050 , I am getting connections are still in  Established state until the program exits, when program exits it clears all the Established connections.

> Connection con =
>   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:impala://10.184.43.100:21050");
>
> con.close();
>
> **///The connection should close here. But its not closing here**
>
> Thread.sleep(20000);
>
> **///Connection is closing here.**

**Why connections to impalad are still alive even after calling the connection.close(). ???? Am i doing something wrong???**

To simulate this please check the below code , where after

```
public class ClouderaJDBCImpalaExample {
// Define a string as the fully qualified class name (FQCN) of
// the desired JDBC driver
static String JDBCDriver = "com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver";
// Define a string as the connection URL
static String ConnectionURL = "jdbc:impala://10.184.43.100:21050";

static{
        try {
            // Register the driver using the class name
            Class.forName(JDBCDriver);
            LogController.logInfoMessage("Impala Driver Loaded.");
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

 Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:impala://10.184.43.100:21050");
        con.close();
        ///The connection should close here. But its not closing here
        Thread.sleep(20000);
       ///Connection is closing here.
}
```

> root@pasapp ~ # netstat -an | grep -i 21050

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21050               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.184.43.100:21050         169.144.48.135:52137        ESTABLISHED
root@pasapp ~ #

Thanks !!!

Comment: This code does not compile. Post the real code.

Comment: Try using isClosed() before and after close() and check what is the outcome

Comment: Most likely the driver has an internal connection pool and doesn't close the physical connection, only the logical handle. It can then return a connection without having to go through the connection setup.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but there is no api to set the restriction of maximum no of physical connection. If I am opening and closing connection . But still physical connections are exits till the program runs.

Comment: I'd say you need to contact Cloudera to get more information or report bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This driver does connection pooling. Your close != the pool's close. No doubt there is some way to configure the pool.